# WSO2 API manager 1.4.0 behind Apache proxy

Tags: apache, proxy, wso2

I've configured an API manager on a private VM and using an Apache (on a second VM) to expose the service.
This way I can use Apache also to map port 9763 to port 80.

I've added the *ProxyPort* in the *catalina-server.xml* and manage to access the STORE but the login form still present the internal IP address.

```
<form id="loginRedirectForm" method="post" action="https://10.1.1.235:9443/store/site/themes/fancy/templates/user/login/redirector.jag">
        <input type="hidden" name="redirectToHTTPS" id="redirectToHTTPS" value="https://10.1.1.235:9443/store/" />
    </form>
```

Where do I have to change the parameter to have the correct address?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround,you can uncomment and change the  configuration of {AM}/repository/conf/carbon.xml file accordingly and continue.

There was a bug[1],when http->https redirection happening,the public ip is changed to internal ip address.This is fixed with next AM release.

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-1720

Thanks;

Comment: Sorry, but accordingly how?

Answer (score 0):

@Luca;
Please edit the `<Hostname>` parameter in your carbon.xml to the public IP and check.